error crear carpeta: DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.) Flutter and Dart
Estoy intentando crear carpetas en google drive utilizando su API. Pero me da el siguiente error
DetailedApiRequestError(status: 403, message: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.)

No se cual sea el problema ya que estoy tomando la informacion del usuario cuando inicia sesion
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn =
GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      drive.DriveApi.driveFileScope,  // Solicita acceso a los archivos creados por la app.
      drive.DriveApi.driveScope,  // Solicita acceso completo a Google Drive.
    ],
  );

Les paso el codigo completo
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class TestFolder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestFolderState createState() => _TestFolderState();
}

class _TestFolderState extends State<TestFolder> {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      drive.DriveApi.driveFileScope,  
      drive.DriveApi.driveScope, 
    ],
  );

  GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;
  drive.DriveApi? _driveApi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        _handleSignIn();
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    final authHeaders = await _currentUser?.authHeaders;
    if (authHeaders == null) return;

    final authenticateClient = _GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
    setState(() {
      _driveApi = drive.DriveApi(authenticateClient);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _createFolderinDrive() async {
    if (_driveApi == null) {
      print('Google Drive API isn't initializate');
      return;
    }

    final folder = drive.File();
    folder.name = "Folder example@example.com";
    folder.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"; 

    try {
      final folderResponse = await _driveApi!.files.create(folder);
      print('Folder Created Successfully in Drive: ${folderResponse.id}');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating folder: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _signIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print('Log in Error: $error');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Create Folder in Google Drive'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _currentUser != null ? _crearCarpetaEnDrive : _signIn,
              child: Text(_currentUser != null ? 'Create Folder in Drive' : 'Google log in'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _GoogleAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  final Map<String, String> _headers;
  final http.Client _client = http.Client();

  _GoogleAuthClient(this._headers);

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) {
    return _client.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));
  }
}

Alguien me puede guiar con esto, ya que no he encontrado una solucion, he leido las API's, el funcionamiento y no encuentro nada, ya habilite la api en Google Cloud Console y tengo los OAuth y me sigue dando el mismo error, he checado los permisos y se que por la parte de Cloud Console no es, y de ahi en mas la informacion que he encontrado es inconclusa.

El mensaje de error indica el problema:

status: 403, message: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

La solicitud no tenía suficientes alcances de autenticación.
Estás definiendo los scopes correctos,
GoogleSignIn(
    scopes: [
      drive.DriveApi.driveFileScope,  // Solicita acceso a los archivos creados por la app.
      drive.DriveApi.driveScope,  // Solicita acceso completo a Google Drive.
    ],
  );

Pero asegura que en la pantalla de consentimiento de Google Cloud Console tengas definido estos scopes:


Para esto ya tengo que tener mi app desplegada verdad?

@BrandonOsmarNuñezVazquez no es necesario, previamente tu puedes realizar pruebas con tu aplicación.

Ya lo cheque, muchas gracias bro, esto funciona a la perfeccion, ahora solo falta hacer unos cambios para lo que realmente necesito.
